# Dropdown in navigation or modal for log in/register?

Tags: navigation, login, dropdown, modal

We've noticed on our website that there's no 'quick access' to users accounts, or to know if they are logged in or not. So I've designed:

1. A dropdown from the my account header in the navigation with links to the sign in/register page, with some other useful links to things like help portal, track my order etc. And for logged in users the dropdown will display more personal links/info to them based on their shopping behaviour.
2. A modal that users can log in through with just 2 input fields, and a link to your register page. For logged in users the icon will be clickable and go to their account page.

Is there any best practice for using either of these? My gut feeling is not using a modal as it's disruptive to a users journey, and the dropdown feels more useful and less intrusive.

Comment: I think both are fine. I see #2 more often than #1. Can you do some observational user testing to see how your users respond to each one?

Comment: Re "_And for logged in users the dropdown will display more personal links/info to them_": What about placing (often used) personal links and (important) info directly on your account header next to the user's name/avatar? See your account info on SE's top-bar right on the page here...

Answer (score 1):

Use the dropdown menu. A modal might see more like a disturbance than an helpful resource. From a users POV they don't usually have the best experiences with modals popping up.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logging in for the first time, specific step or page... - **use a modal window.**

If the user is already logged in - **dropdown and the user's avatar.**

Also, I think this article will be useful to you in your research - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/innovative-techniques-to-simplify-signups-and-logins/